# Every spectrum is the homotopy colimit of shifted suspension spectra

Tags: stable-homotopy, limits-and-colimits, stable-homotopy-category

Let $X$ be a spectrum. In various places, I have encountered the statement that
$$
X \simeq \text{hocolim}_n \Sigma^{\infty-n}X_n.
$$
I was wondering how this homotopy colimit is defined, and why we have such an equivalence.

The particular model for spectra I use is the one defined in Adams' blue book.

Comment: If you have a countable sequence of maps in a triangulated category, you can build an object which you can meaningfully call the homotopy colimit. Taking this approach in the setting of symmetric spectra, you can read a proof of the result in Proposition II.5.12 in Schwede's Symmetric Spectra book project.